# SSH Tunnel to CUPS how to give admin password?

Tags: ssh-tunnel, cups

I am tunneling to distant network and want to admin printer of one of the machine (say 192.168.0.10) so I :

```
ssh -L8080:192.168.0.10:631 distantIP
```

Now on my browser localhost:8080 I happily get the CUPS informations but when I try to administrate, the cups server only send : 'FORBIDDEN' message and do not let me chance to authenticate.
Is there a way to get round this behavior ?

Comment: One should notice if I allow direct access to my machine 192.168.0.10 from outside world via port forwarding everything goes well. But it wont be as convenient and as secured as via the entry machine of the distant network.